# Why does VBA asks me for Macro Name when I press Run?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA. Below is a code to alert the user of the blank cell before printing:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F23").Value = "" Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox ("Please populate F23")
    End If
End Sub
```

However, when I press. run, it prompts me for Macro name. May I know why? And what is the solution?

Comment: You are not supposed to press "Run" for `Workbook_BeforePrint`. It will auto execute when you print. If you want to run it with a click then in a module put the code in say `Sub Sample()... End Sub`

Answer (score 2):

Your macro has a non-optional parameter, `Cancel`.  When you press <kbd>F5</kbd>, VBA detects this parameter, determines that it cannot run the macro without it, and then opens the generic "Run Macro" screen.

If you wish to run it without triggering the Event (i.e. Printing), then you will need to put the following code into either another Subroutine, or into the Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in VBA) and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run  it from there:

```vb
Workbook_BeforePrint False
```

(This passes the argument `False` to the Parameter `Cancel`)